# document.getElementsByClassName for JavaScript created elements

Tags: javascript

I dynamically created various images and other elements within various div elements and assigned a class to them, like:

```
divOM = document.getElementById('omain');
kd = document.createElement('img');
kd.src = 'pics/k0.jpg';
kd.class = 'mww';
divOM.appendChild(kd);
```

This works well – the debugger shows the desired result (# children with class ‘mww’).  I have the (maybe naïve) hope that

```
wlist = document.getElementsByClassName('mww')
```

gives me all elements which have class=’mww’, but unfortunately it doesn’t. The debugger shows length:0 for wlist!?? Is it possible that document.getElementsByClassName doesn’t work for dynamically created elements?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be `.className`, not `.class`.

`class` is a reserved word in JavaScript.

Or use the [Class List API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList):

```
kd.classList.add('mww');
```

Comment: Actually, since ES5 (2009) `kd.class = 'mww';` has been perfectly valid from a code perspective. The problem is that the DOM bindings for this stuff were created before that change and in ES3 (1999, the version just before ES5) `kd.class = 'mww';` *wasn't* valid. :-|

Comment: Interesting, didn't realise that.

Comment: Btw, reserved words **can** be used as object properties now (that's why `promise.catch`, `generator.throw` and `import(...).default` work), but the designers of the DOM made it that way because it wasn't always so.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oh, I managed to write the same thing in different words (I didn't see your comment while I was typing)

Comment: @FZs - But yours has great examples! :-)

Comment: Excellent! Thanks a lot. It works with .className!